# What is the meaning of 'get far'

Tags: meaning

> If you do not understand this basic command(in computer),  you're not
> going to get far.

What is the meaning of 'get far' here?

Comment: It's a metaphorical reference invoking an image of a pathway stretching from *understanding **nothing** about computers* at one end, to *understanding **everything** about computers* at the other end. If you don't ***get / travel far*** down that road, you'll be stuck at the "I don't understand computers" end of things, which isn't where you want to be.

Comment: If you put your answers in the comments you won't get far.

Comment: @Dan, if you don't flag answers in comments, nothing much will happen about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"get far" means to go to a great distance.  Metaphorically it means to achieve a lot in particular field (eg in the field of computer programming). Imagine learning something as being like a path.

It is often used in the negative. "He won't get far" means "He won't achieve much."

As a positive, "go far" is more common - with the same meaning.